# What is the difference between defn- and defn ^:private in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, ring, defn

Both seem to denote a private function, similiar to that found in most OOP languages. Is there a functional difference or is one just syntactic sugar?

I've seen defn ^:private used in the context of the handler of a ring application.

Comment: What was the motivation for adding the tag based approach to making it private? If your assertion is true, it would look like they introduced syntactic salt rather than sugar?

Comment: BTW, note that to be on-topic here, a question should be about a "specific problem you actually face"; that's a definition that excludes questions that are just matters of curiosity.

Comment: Mm? The metadata-tagging approach lets you also use, say, `^:const` or `^:debug` or `^:dynamic`; it's a general feature, not specific to marking things private.

Comment: I'd suggest starting with https://clojure.org/reference/metadata

Comment: ...the other thing to note is that in hindsight, `defn-` is considered a bad idea; it's still there because breaking backwards compatibility is considered even worse.

Comment: (Reading through the Clojure codebase, the first use of metadata macros in Clojure itself was in 1.3; support for `^:private` as sugar for `^{:private true}` was added in June of 2010; adding `^` to the reader happened in April 2010 -- you still had `:private` as metadata before that, but it was using much wordier syntax one had to use `with-meta` for, hence wanting to have something like `defn-` to make it reasonably terse/workable).

Comment: (I would write an answer to the above effect, but see the preceding argument that the question as a whole is off-topic, or the source for that argument: [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design))

Answer (score 5):

In answer to the original question: there is no difference.

```
user=> (defn- a1 [b] b)
#'user/a1
user=> (defn ^:private a2 [b] b)
#'user/a2
user=> (meta #'a1)
{:private true, :arglists ([b]), :line 1, :column 1, :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH", :name a1, :ns #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0xbaf1bb3 "user"]}
user=> (meta #'a2)
{:private true, :arglists ([b]), :line 1, :column 1, :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH", :name a2, :ns #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0xbaf1bb3 "user"]}
user=> (source defn-)
(defmacro defn-
  "same as defn, yielding non-public def"
  {:added "1.0"}
  [name & decls]
    (list* `defn (with-meta name (assoc (meta name) :private true)) decls))
nil
user=>
```

As we can see from the source of `defn-` it is functionally identically to `defn` with `:private true` metadata added to the `name` symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the macro `defn-`, it is just a shorthand for "private" functions. The long form looks like:

```
(defn ^:private foo [args] ...)
```

However, this is just a hint to the user that one shouldn't use these functions. It is easy for testing, etc to work around this weak "private" restriction. Due to the hassle I never use so-called "private" functions (I do sometimes use metadata `^:no-doc` and names like `foo-impl` to indicate a fn is not a part of the public-facing API and should be ignored by library users).

You can view the definition of `defn-` [in the Clojure source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/38bafca9e76cd6625d8dce5fb6d16b87845c8b9d/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4925) for more details.

Comment: That's a good point for the OP: private functions in Clojure can still be called -- unlike many languages that prevent this. In Clojure, you can put `#'` in front of a private function to call it from another namespace.